# When to use external style sheet and the other types?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in html/css, i want to know when i should use external ,internal,inline style sheets respectively. What makes the big difference.?  [I read a couple of answers on the same site] but i need something which is more clear.

Comment: May be you can check this link:-https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html

Comment: *"I read a couple of answers on the same site] but i need something which is more clear."* - How are we gonna give better answers when we don't know the original ones.

Answer (score 1):

External stylesheets can be cached and reused between different pages and reloads of the same page.

Style elements don't require an additional HTTP request and can provide a performance boost for the initial load of a page, at the cost of losing caching.

Which is better depends on your priorities. Some people recommend using a style element for the above-the-fold content of a site's homepage to minimise the time-to-render (with the rest of the CSS being loaded asynchronously to avoid blocking — this adds complexity).

Style attributes generally just provide an increased maintenance cost, but are better supported in HTML formatted email.